# Uploading file to folder other than default OneDrive REST

Tags: c#, onedrive

So I'm PUTing a file onto one drive, my URI looks like
https://apis.live.net/v5.0/me/skydrive/files/?access_token=12345

however, if I try and change the folder to, say, Documents:

https://apis.live.net/v5.0/me/skydrive/files/Documents?access_token=12345

or

https://apis.live.net/v5.0/me/skydrive/Documents/files?access_token=12345

I'll get a HTTP 400 (bad request error).

One "workaround" could be to query the top level directory of the onedrive, done by reading the JSON response from the first URI about, and then suck out the upload_location for a desired folder, however I feel this is a bit long winded. From the *Upload a File* section in
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn659726.aspx
I got the impression I should be able to specify a friendly folder path.

I'm positive it's a really simple answer, but I've wasted long enough on it and hopefully this will serve as a resource for those having the same issue (haven't been able to find elsewhere except for an unanswered question here http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/forum/sdfiles-sdupload/how-to-upload-a-file-to-a-specific-folder-created/0d57e43c-a3ec-42fc-b3b7-f15a17b2836f)

Thanks

Comment: If you want full path support you may want to consider our new API, see http://onedrive.github.io/README.htm#item-resource

Comment: I've looked at it. It's still not obvious to me. For example, from https://dev.onedrive.com/items/upload_put.htm, I still can't work out to how upload a file using a PUT request anywhere other than the default files directory. I currently have  PUT https://apis.live.net/v5.0/me/skydrive/files/HelloWorld.txt?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN

but instead of files directory (which seems to be the top directory of onedrive?), I want to put it in the my_photos folder. I just want the verbatim URI

Comment: The new API would look something like `PUT https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0/drive/root:/Documents/newfile.txt:/content`

Answer (score 1):

Based on your examples I think you just need to change Documents -> my_documents and then the scenario will work like you'd want.  Here is the relative excerpt from the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn659731.aspx).

Use friendly names to access certain OneDrive folders
To access certain OneDrive folders, you can use friendly names instead of folder IDs. Use the following friendly names to access these corresponding folders in the OneDrive UI:

- USER_ID/skydrive/camera_roll represents the OneDrive camera roll folder.
- USER_ID/skydrive/my_documents represents the Documents folder.
- USER_ID/skydrive/my_photos represents the Pictures folder.
- USER_ID/skydrive/public_documents represents the Public folder.

In each case, replace USER_ID with either me for the signed-in user or a user ID for any other consenting user.
For example, to read the Documents folder's properties, use a REST API call to the folder's ID, like this.

```
 GET https://apis.live.net/v5.0/folder.a6b2a7e8f2515e5e.A6B2A7E8F2515E5E!110?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN
```

Comment: I tried: https://apis.live.net/v5.0/me/skydrive/my_photos/myFileIWantToUpload.jpg?access_token=123xyz, but  it doesn't seem to work. I get a JSON response:
{
   "error": {
      "code": "request_url_invalid", 
      "message": "The URL contains the path 'myFileIWantToUpload.jpg', which isn't supported."
   }
}

Answer (score 0):

Try the API's listed in the following link:
https://dev.onedrive.com/README.htm#
These work fine for me.